# How do i make my python food calculator consistent?

Tags: python

```
while 1:
    pie = 50
    pieR = pie
    pieRem = pieR - buy
    print("We have ", pieRem, "pie(s) left!")
    buy = int(input("How many pies would you like?  "))
    pieCost = 5
    Pie = pieCost * buy
    if buy == 1:
        print(pieCost)
        pieS = pieR - buy
    elif buy > 1:
        print(Pie * 0.75)
    else:
        print("Please enter how many pies you would like!")
```

When I open the console, it asks how many pies I would like to buy, and I made it so the number of pies we have left, shows, but the value of pie refreshes every time. So if I chose that I wanted 2 pies the first time it would say we have 48 pies left (default pie value is 50) and then after it asks me the second time and i enter 3, instead of going down to 45, it refreshes and goes down to 47.

I hope I explained this well, I hope someone knows how to fix this, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Every time your code loops back to the beginning, `pie` gets redefined to 50. You'll want to define the variable `pie` outside of the `while` loop:

```
pie = 50
while 1:
    ...
```

---

Sorry, but your code is a mess, especially with variable names. I cleaned it up for you:

```
buy = 0
pies = 50
cost = 5
while 1:
    print("We have ", pies, "pie(s) left!")
    buy = int(input("How many pies would you like?  "))   
    price = cost * buy
    if buy == 1:
        print(price)
        pies -= 1
    elif buy > 1:
        print(buy * 0.75)
        pies -= buy
    else:
        print("Please enter how many pies you would like!")
```

Comment: check my answer itworks. @Haidro has some mistake like `pies-buy` etc

Comment: my answer very clean,, it deals with `pie less than 1` and if `buy >pies` etc also it prints the cost corectly for `buy >1` yours have some error.

Comment: @suhail But that might not be what the OP wants

Comment: first of all say for `buy=2`, it will print `2*.75` i thing that is wrong it must be `5*2*.75` right. and if `buy=100` then the next loop prints `We have -50 pies left` what does that mean. but my code handle all these

Comment: @suhail Like I said, it depends on what the OP wants.

Comment: hey don't fight we are people to help for free. Just for GOOD :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

as from @Haidros code below

```
buy,pies,cost = 0,50,5
while 1:
    if pies<1:
        print ('Sorry no pies left' )
        break
    print("We have ", pies, "pie(s) left!")
    buy = int(input("How many pies would you like?  "))
    if pies-buy<0:buy = int(input("Only %s pies remaining How many pies would you like?"%pies))                  
    if buy>0:
        if buy==1:print(cost*buy)
        else:print(cost*buy * 0.75)
        pies-=buy       
    else:
        print("Please enter how many pies you would like!")
```

Comment: This is just a copy of my answer, with dense code, which looks awful: `Sparse is better than dense.`

Comment: @Haidro sorry i will mention your name in the code. sorry!! :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you use classes and objects you do away with global variables and you can easily extend the code to other products (eg: croissants, bagels, soup, coffee, sandwiches or whatever.. )

```
class pies:
""" Object To Sell Pies """

def __init__(self):
    """ Constructor And Initialise Attributes """       
    self.pies=50
    self.amount = 0     
    self.cost = 5

def buy(self,buy):
    """ Method To Buy Pies """       

    if (buy > self.pies):
        print "Sorry Only %d Pies in Stock" % self.pies
    elif (self.pies >= 1):
        self.pies =self.pies - buy
        print "Cost is : %.02f" % ( 0.75 * buy )
        print "We have %d and pies in stock" % (self.pies) 
    elif (self.pies == 1):
        self.pies =self.pies - buy
        print "Cost is : %.02f" % ( self.cost * buy )
        print "We have %d pies in stock now" % (self.pies) 

    else:
        print "Sorry Pies Out of Stock !"  
        self.buy = 0
        self.pies = 0
```

Save the code above as pieobject.py then call it with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from pieobject import pies

p = pies()

while True:

    try:
        amount=int(raw_input('Enter number of pies to buy:'))
    except ValueError:
        print "Not a number"       
        break

    os.system('clear')  
    p.buy(amount)
```